# How do I dynamically sort nested entities using Spring Data's Sort?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have the following JPQL query in a Spring Data Repository:

```
public interface CarRepository extends Repository<Car, Integer> {
    
    @Query("select distinct c.model from Car c where c.id in :ids")
    Set<Model> findDistinctModelByIdIn(@Param("ids") Set<Integer> ids, Sort sort);
}
```

A client calls the query as follows (which is exposed via Spring Data REST):

```
http://localhost:8080/api/cars/search/findDistinctModelByIdIn?ids=1,33,55,43&sort=model.name,desc
```

However, the results are returned unsorted. How can I sort based on the client sort request parameter?

Does Spring only sort on the domain type the repository manages (e.g., only `Car` not `Model`)?

**Update**

Here is my domain model:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Car {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private Model model;
}

@Entity
@Data
public class Model {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

**Update**

After turning on trace for org.springframework.web, I found the following:

> 2023-02-09T12:20:16.315-06:00 TRACE 21812 --- [io-9006-exec-10]
> o.s.web.method.HandlerMethod             : Arguments:
> [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation@6e3e0c99,
> {ids=[33283,37901], sort=[model.name,desc]}, findDistinctModelByIdIn,
> DefaultedPageable(pageable=Page request [number: 0, size 20, sort:
> UNSORTED], isDefault=true), UNSORTED,
> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler...

However, when using @Yuriy-Tsarkov project, the following is logged:

> 2023-02-09T12:16:17.818-06:00 TRACE 22460 --- [nio-8097-exec-1]
> o.s.web.method.HandlerMethod             : Arguments:
> [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation@3e78567e,
> {ids=[33283,37901], sort=[model.name,desc]}, findDistinctModelByIdIn,
> DefaultedPageable(pageable=Page request [number: 0, size 20, sort:
> model.name: DESC], isDefault=false), model.name: DESC,
> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler...

So, Spring is perceiving some difference even though I'm using the exact same version of dependencies and my code & config from what I can tell is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Summary**

Spring Data will not sort on a nested entity that has its own repository and is exported (which is the default).

**Details**

After further research, I found the answer as to why [@yuriy-tsarkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7214142/yuriy-tsarkov) [application](https://github.com/yura2201/simple-jpa-h2/tree/so-74295257) is able to sort on nested entity but my application is **not** able.

**Cause of the Problem**

I have a repository for the nested entity, `Model`:

```
public interface ModelRepository extends Repository<Model, Integer> {
    //various method defs    
}
```

If you add a `ToyRepository` to @yuriy-tsarkov application, it will fail to sort `Toy`s returned by his `PetRepository` just like my application fails to sort `Model`s returned by the `CarRepository`.

**Why?**

Because once `Model` (or `Toy` in the case of yuriy-tsarkov `app) has its own repository, it is considered a linkable association. That is,  org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.mapping.Associations.isLinkableAssociation(PersistentProperty<?>)` returns true for the `model` (`toy`) association. It ultimately returns the boolean from `isMapped` which is also true :

```
@Override
public boolean isMapped(PersistentProperty<?> property) {
    return repositories.hasRepositoryFor(property.getActualType()) && super.isMapped(property);
}
```

This is because repositories.hasRepositoryFor returns true b/c as noted above I have a repository for `Model` and `super.isMapped` also returns true. `super.isMapped` return false only if  `@RestResource(exported=false)` is defined. Since I didn't define that, it return true.

(I believe this may make sense because my `Model` might be only represented with links. That said, it does seem like I could still may want those links sorted by the model name.)

**Solution**

In my case I need a repository that manages `Model` entities. So, I cannot simply remove the `ModelRepository`.

I can, however, allow the nested entity prop, `model`, to not be exported:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Car {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @RestResource(exported=false)
    private Model model;
}
```

That allows `super.isMapped` to return false (because it is not an exported resource). Then sorting does work b/c it's not simply links potentially being returned.

I feel this solution is a workaround though and that Spring Data Rest should still be able to sort on a attribute even if only links are provided. In my scenario, the repo wasn't providing links anyway (even without the @RestResource).

Answer (score 1):

> Does Spring only sort on the domain type the repository manages (e.g., only Car not Model)?

Actually, does. I've modeled a case like yours and didn't face any problems. [Here it is](https://github.com/yura2201/simple-jpa-h2/tree/so-74295257). What if the cornerstone is in the `Spring`s version? It often happens that in some versions the internal implementation is very different...

Comment: Nice repo! for `http://localhost:8097/pets/search/findDistinctSetByIdIn?ids=1,2,3`, i get a result, but issuing `...&sort=name` results in 500,  `...&sort=toys.name[,desc]` produces no error, but has no effect.

Comment: @xerx593 Thank you! There is a `favoriteToy` property in the `Pet` entity, so the correct sort is `sort=favoriteToy.name, desc`

Comment: ..I could reproduce OP issue (with latest spring-boot release), but still cannot find a significant error/difference to your (working) repo.. ;(

Comment: Thanks for the repo! Unfortunately, my issue remains even after moving to Spring Boot 2.7.5. I have to put the query into the `ModelRepository` to sort.

Comment: @yuriy-tsarkov - Your project sorts it correctly. Like xerx593, I can't seem to find a notable difference. We're now using the same Spring Boot version.

Comment: I took your project and put my entities, repo and SQL server data source. Interestingly enough the sort on my entities works in your project. I noticed one other difference: I had to indicate `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` to avoid underscores. I wonder if there some other setting on project that is allowing sort to work in yours but not mine

Comment: it sounds weirdly.. try do enable sql logging: `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`, `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true`, `logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE` and run some test on your code and mine to see if `order by` clause has been added to the request during its generation. And check a certain class type of a `Set` in the resultset. To provide a sortability it should be something like `LinkedHashSet`. What if it depends on default set implementations in different framework versions?

Comment: @yuriy-tsarkov - Sorry for the delay. I added logging and found a difference. Updated the OP.

Comment: @xerx593 - Tagging you here as well since I know that you replicated my issue. I believe my answer may explain why you were able to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

Spring supports that for sure, the only thing is that it performs a crossjoin, which means you'll lose the entities with a null Model from the result.

To debug this I would suggest you add this config:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
```

Then you can check in the console/ logs the executed db query and see if the sorting was there, hence find whether the problem is in the query generation or in the data.